# If $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ are embeddings, show that $X=X_1\sqcup X_2,Y=Y_1\sqcup Y_2$ s.t. $f|X_1:X_1\cong Y_1, g|Y_2:Y_2\cong X_2$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have to prove

> If $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ are embeddings, show that there are $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ s.t. $X=X_1\sqcup X_2,Y=Y_1\sqcup Y_2$ (where $\sqcup$ denotes a disjoint union of sets) and $f|X_1:X_1\cong Y_1, g|Y_2:Y_2\cong X_2$

My first confusion is that this really doesn't seem to be about topology, but just about set-theory. Regardless, here is my idea:

We must have 
$$f(X_1)=Y-Y_2$$
$$g(Y_2)=X-X_1$$
Now by solving this like a linear system we find
$$f(X_1)=Y-g^{-1}(X-X_1)=g^{-1}(X_1)$$
Which suggests to me the following construction: construct a set $X_1$ as follows:
$$X_1^0=X-g(Y)$$
$$X_1^{n+1}=X_1^n\bigcup g(f(X_1^n))$$

Now I'm don't know anything about transfinite recursion, which I believe is what we need to utilise here in order to conclude that this proces does in fact specify a set $X_1$.

Now we set $X_2=X-X_1$, $Y_1=f(X_1)$, $Y_2=Y-Y_1$. Now we only need to show that $f(X_1)=Y_1$ and $g(Y_2)=X_2$. The first one is true by definition and for the second one:

$x\in g(Y_2)$. Suppose $x\not\in X_2$, so $x\in X_1$. Then either $x\in X_1^0$, which is not possible since $x\in g(Y)$. Or $x\in X_1^n$ for $n>N$. However, then we can write $x=g(f(x'))$ for some $x'\in X_1^N\subset X_1$, so $x\in g(f(X_1))=g(Y_1)$, which is a contradiction, since $g$ is injective and $Y_2=Y-Y_1$.

$x\in X_2$. Suppose $g^{-1}(x)\not\in Y_2$, so $g^{-1}(x)\in Y_1=f(X_1)$. So then $x=g(f(x'))$ for some $x'\in X_1$. But then also $x\in X_1$ by construction of $X_1$, which is a contradiction.

---

I think this is kind of correct, but not completely. My main problem with it is that I'm not sure if $X_1$ is well defined.

I'm also a bit confused by the fact that this seems to just be a set-theory question, not at all a topology question. Is this true? I know that if $f:X\to f(X)\subset Y$ is a homeomorphism, then $f|A:A\to f(A)\subset Y$ is also a homeomorphism, so the fact that $f,g$ are homeomorphisms doesn't seem that relevant...

So any comment on the correctness of this proof would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you are right. If those decompositions are just disjoint unions and not topological sum decomposions (in which case I don't think it holds), than this is really just Cantor–Benstein theorem plus the observation that a restriction of an embedding is a homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: @user87690 Yes it's just a normal disjoint union, I'll include that in the question. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @user87690 I didn't know about the Cantor–Benstein theorem, but something very similar to this theorem was given as a hint to the exercise. However, I didn't know what to do with it. Could you maybe explain how we can use this theorem to do this more easily? Or do you not really use the conclusion of the theorem, but more so the same construction in both proofs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Theorem (Cantor–Bernstein, also known as Cantor–Bernstein–Schöder).* Let $X, Y$ be sets. If there exists $f: X \to Y$ injective and $g: Y \to X$ injective, then there exists a bijection between $X$ and $Y$.

There are various proofs of the theorem including your construction. But these proofs in fact prove more: the bijection is such that $X = X_1 \sqcup X_2$, $Y = Y_1 \sqcup Y_2$ and $f$ bijectively maps $X_1$ onto $Y_1$ and $g$ bijectively maps $Y_2$ onto $X_2$. That is your proposition without topology.

As you have observed, the topological part is easy: if $X, Y$ are also topological spaces and $f, g$ are embeddings, then the bijections between the parts are homeomorphisms.

So proving your proposition reduces to proving Cantor–Bernstein in one way or another, which is a standard thing.

Comment: Oke so just to be clear: the additional constraint that the bijection be such that $X = X_1 \sqcup X_2$ and $Y = Y_1 \sqcup Y_2$ is not a direct result of the theorem, but more so a nice 'bonus' as a result of the proof we used?

Comment: What I mean is that from the existence of the bijection we cannot immediately conclude the additional constraints are also satisfied, without looking a the construction used in the proof right?

Comment: Yes you are right. The traditional formulation of the theorem gives you just some bijection. You now nothing about it; it just exists. Nevertheless, all proofs of Cantor–Bernstein I know give the stronger result, so it should be a part of the formulation of the theorem, so one can use it.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications and time.

Comment: You are welcome.